# Why is my variable appending?

Tags: javascript

So I have a variable and I am making a save feature using local storage. As it is very easy to use it. Yet I am having this issue. When I get the JS variable again it appends for some reason. The variable gold increments every second.

This is my get item from local storage.

```
function getSaveItem(item) {
    return localStorage.getItem(item);
}
```

> Before save game: Gold: 98
>
> After and calling the variable again: Gold 9811111

Instead of adding it to 99, 100, 101, 102. It adds 1 to the end.

Comment: localstorage can only store strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt` since the values are stored as strings. Otherwise it treats them like strings "A" + "A" = "AA" and "1" + "1" = "11"

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 9 minutes!